# get_post_meta is not working inside shortcode

Tags: custom-post-types, loop, shortcode

The code below is a bootstrap slider turned into a custom post type.This custom post type is working by itself but when i try to put it in shortcode it doesn't work.Specifically get_post_meta isn't working because i can see the attachment file working properly

```
<section id="reviews" class="reviews page">
            <div class="container wow fadeInUp">
                <div class="row">
                    <h1 class="sr-only"><?php echo $testimonialsArr['title']; ?></h1>
                    <div id="review-slider" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false">
                        <div class="col-xs-12">

                            <?php 

                                $args=array(

                                    'post_type' => 'testimonials',
                                    'order'    => 'ASC'

                                );

                                $testimonialQuery = new WP_Query($args);

                            ?>
                            <?php if ( $testimonialQuery->have_posts() ) :?>
                            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                            <?php  while( $testimonialQuery->have_posts() ) : $testimonialQuery->the_post(); 

                                $testimonialName = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_published_testimonial_name_key',true);
                                var_dump($testimonialName);


                            ?>

                                <li data-target="#review-slider" data-slide-to="<?php echo $testimonialQuery->current_post ?>" class="<?php if( $testimonialQuery->current_post == 0 ):?>active<?php endif;?> wow fadeInLeft" data-wow-delay="0.3s"><?php echo $testimonialName;?></li>

                            <?php endwhile; ?>

                            </ol>
                            <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                                    <?php if ( $testimonialQuery->have_posts() ) : while( $testimonialQuery->have_posts() ) : $testimonialQuery->the_post();

                                        $testimonialText = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_published_testimonial_text_key',true);
                                        $testimonialAvatar = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id() );
                                        $testimonialLink = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_published_testimonial_url_key',true);

                                    ?>

                                    <div class="item <?php if( $testimonialQuery->current_post == 0 ):?>active<?php endif;?> clearfix fadeInUp delay-2">
                                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                                            <blockquote>

                                                <?php echo $testimonialText; ?>

                                            </blockquote>
                                        </div>


                                        <div class="col-xs-12 blockquote-cite">
                                            <div class="row no-gutter">
                                                <div class="col-xs-2 col-xs-offset-4 col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-5 col-md-1 col-md-offset-6">
                                                    <span class="cite-img"><img src="<?php echo $testimonialAvatar;?>" class="img-responsive" alt="published-img"></span>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-5 col-md-5">
                                                    <div class="cite-right">
                                                        <span class="cite-name">Adam Butler</span>
                                                        <?php if($testimonialLink):?>
                                                            <span class="cite-url"><a href="<?php echo $testimonialLink; ?>"><?php echo $testimonialLink; ?></a></span>
                                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                    </div><!-- end item -->
                                        <?php endwhile;?>
                                        <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                    </div>
                                    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
                                </div>
                             </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div><!-- End: .row -->
            </div><!-- End: .container-->
        </section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the issue is that in the shortcode you don't actually have access to the `global $post` object.

1. You could switch out your WP_Query with a `get_posts()` that returns an array.
2. You could use `get_the_ID();`.
3. You could call `global $post` at the top of your shortcode function.

The problem is that `global $post` is technically out of scope when used in this function. The Loop and Custom WP_Queries will work fine in templates because `wp()` puts `$post` in the global namespace for the templates to use whenever template is loaded all behind the scenes. As soon as you add any generic function, shortcode callback function, or `add_shortcode()` passing in an anonymous function as a 2nd parameter, the global variables will be out of scope until you bring them into scope by calling `global $post`.

To add onto this. The reason the `get_*()` functions work ( such as 
`get_the_title()` or `get_the_ID()` ) is because they all call `get_post()` which uses the `global $post` and bubbles the value upward.

To read more about this you can check out [PHP Variable Scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) or [Variable Scope and WordPress](https://wpshout.com/php-globals-variable-scope-wordpress/) by David Hayes

Comment: thank you it solved the problem.Can you direct me to a resource where i can learn more about this?

Comment: @user16072 I've updated this answer to provide further clarification.